# How much would private SO Enterprise cost for about 100 users?

Tags: support, so-enterprise

I was wondering if someone can give some estimate how much would SO Enterprise cost for about 100 users?

I don't need exact numbers or anything, just some guiding price. I know there is an option to request a demo, but from my experience with other enterprise offerings once you request a demo then unstoppable flow of cold calls and emails start pouring in, so I would rather avoid this option for now until I know a bit more on the pricing model and estimated cost.

Comment: Technically, when you requested a demo, all follow up calls are no longer cold calls...

Comment: Also note that the wiki says *built for large organizations that generally plan to support 500 or more users*. I guess the pricing accounts for that guidance as well.

Comment: I guess you have a point, however on the request demo page there is an option to select 0 - 250 users.

Comment: Yeah, it is worth a try but I doubt if they will release pricing to the public. If they wanted I expect they would have already done.

Comment: I know, I am not even hoping that someone from the sales team will reply, but maybe if someone has already requested demo or quote can give some info - again I don't need exact numbers but at least some guidance - after all if the price is completely out of our budget it is pointless to request a demo etc.

Comment: There is some more info [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326380/578411) but in the comments the pricing is still kept vague, also due to your own hosting requirements.

Comment: I assume there is no fixed price, i.e. it's case-by-case pricing, depending on factors like company size, custom features, type of support, etc. You really better contact SE in private, either email or phone, and they'll give you what you want.

Comment: Bit of a historical note: for years, we sold Enterprise as a product with a fixed base price for a fixed set of features (and for 100 users would've probably tried very hard to push you in a different direction, since we wouldn't have been doing you any favors). We've taken a different approach recently, both in terms of the software itself and in how it is rolled out, hence the desire to work as closely as possible with the folks using it; this may change in the future, but for now it's likely to *save* both of us a good deal of time and frustration.

Comment: Man I get annoyed when companies don't publish prices. I think taking this approach tarnishes SO's otherwise excellent reputation.

Answer (score 19):

> I know there is an option to request a demo, but from my experience with other enterprise offerings once you request a demo then unstoppable flow of cold calls and emails start pouring in

That's not how we run our sales organization. One rule all our sales people are told during onboarding is - don't spam. We take this very seriously (people have been fired for spamming).

As others have commented - you need to ask for a demo. Someone will get in touch with you. I can pretty much guarantee you will not get an "unstoppable flow of cold calls and emails" - and if you do? Complain - we will deal with the person appropriately.

Comment: Often developers don't want any calls or emails at all. I'm sure Joel explains why on his blog somewhere.

Comment: Is it really too much to ask to give us *some* estimate as to how much this costs? At least some ballpark? To me, this seems really silly. I've seen some wild estimates here and there just because there isn't any information released.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. The question was "Estimate plz". This is essentially a link-only answer, saying "Your estimate is over here".

Comment: @RobertColumbia - Ask and ye shall (eventually) receive

Answer (score 11):

### Approx $20K per annum based on 100 users*

[This website](https://venturebeat.com/2018/05/03/stack-overflow-for-teams-lets-any-group-use-the-qa-platform-internally/) offers a ballpark estimate.

> Stack Overflow for Teams costs $10 per month for up to 10 users, with
> each additional user costing $5 per month (or $50 per year). **For
> reference, Stack Overflow Enterprise costs around $200 per user per
> year, although the use case there is different.** That version is
> typically hosted on premises or on an enterprise’s cloud, is
> accessible via a different URL, and is separate from stackoverflow.com
> (it doesn’t include any of the public content).
>
> <sub><sup>[Venturebeat: Stack Overflow for Teams lets any group use the Q&A platform internally](https://venturebeat.com/2018/05/03/stack-overflow-for-teams-lets-any-group-use-the-qa-platform-internally/)</sup></sub>

*<sub>Please note that these figures are estimates only (your use case may vary), are a year out of date and the [latest advisory from SO is that the Enterprise product is intended for groups of 500+ employees.](https://stackoverflow.com/pricing)</sub>

Comment: Except we wouldn't sell enterprise to a group that small (that's what Shog is saying in his comment on the question). We generally set a minimum of ~500. Teams has been added since then and is the better solution for a group of that size. https://stackoverflow.com/pricing

Comment: @Catija - TBH his comment was somewhat ambiguous and boiled down to three points a) You've sold/considered selling it *in the past* to groups this small b) You'd *discourage* them from doing so at present and c) This might be subject to change in the future.

Comment: @Catija - That being said, I still think it's useful and indicative to give people a ball-park figure, something that SO seems reluctant to do.